# Выдает ошибку TypeError: warn_the_sheep_begin() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'herd'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
herd =['sheep', 'sheep', 'sheep', 'sheep', 'sheep', 'wolf', 'sheep', 'sheep']
def where_wolf():
    for i in range (0,len(herd)):
        if herd[i]=='wolf':
            return i
i = where_wolf()

def warn_the_sheep_begin(herd):
    i = i+1
    while herd[i]=='sheep':
        herd.remove(i)
        i = i+1
        return herd
print(warn_the_sheep_begin())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

у вас функция требует входной параметр

```
def warn_the_sheep_begin(herd)
```

но вы вызываете ее без параметра

```
print(warn_the_sheep_begin())
```

когда вы это исправите, то получите ошибку в строке

```
def warn_the_sheep_begin(herd):
    i = i+1 # <- ошибка тут
```

потому что вы пытаетесь изменить внешнюю переменную, а питон этого не любит, как только вы начинаете менять переменную она становится локальной, а локальная переменная `i` в функции `warn_the_sheep_begin` не определена

когда вы исправите эту ошибку, то следующая будет логической:

```
    herd.remove(i)
    i = i+1
```

нельзя удалять из списка элемент, а потом еще и делать шаг вперед, так вы легко будете выходить за границы, удалять не те элементы и не удалять которые нужно

затем при других данных вы словите ошибку вот здесь

```
i = where_wolf()
```

ведь если волк не найден, то функция `where_wolf` ничего не возвращает, т.е. будет возвращено `None`, а вы это никак не обрабатываете, считая что в `i` всегда число

далее у вас ошибка в цикле `while`

```
while herd[i]=='sheep':
    herd.remove(i)
    i = i+1
    return herd
```

в чем смысл цикла, если вы его сразу прерываете через `return`

кроме того в функции `warn_the_sheep_begin` у вас опять нет общего `return` из-за чего функция будет возвращать `None` если волки идут один за другим

**P.S.**

это вообще ваш код или вы пытаетесь что-то наваять на чужом, но с нулевыми знаниями в питоне?

**P.P.S.**

как я понимаю, **ваш?** код должен был делать только это:

```
herd = ['sheep', 'sheep', 'sheep', 'sheep', 'sheep', 'wolf', 'sheep', 'sheep', 'wolf']


def warn_the_sheep_begin(herd):
    start = herd.index('wolf') if 'wolf' in herd else -1

    if start == -1:
        return herd

    finish = herd.index('wolf', start + 1) if 'wolf' in herd[start + 1:] else -1

    return herd[:start + 1] + (herd[finish:] if finish != -1 else [])


print(warn_the_sheep_begin(herd))
```

**P.P.P.S.**

вот так функция даже попонятнее и побыстрее будет

```
def warn_the_sheep_begin(herd):
    try:
        start = herd.index('wolf')
    except ValueError:
        return herd

    try:
        finish = herd.index('wolf', start + 1)
    except ValueError:
        return herd[:start + 1]

    return herd[:start + 1] + herd[finish:]
```

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ, насчет нулевых знания й я не отрицаю, я новичок и пока учусь